# LOGIT Regression with multiple fixed effects - STATA

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, fixed-effects-model, clustered-standard-errors, clogit

For my thesis I am using as dependent variable the fraction of cash as part of the total price offered by the bidder. So, it's a fractional response that lies between [0,1]. I am not sure which regression should I use in Stata.

Also, my sample comprises 500 acquisitions in Europe announced in the period 2002-2016 from companies in different sectors (some companies have multiple acquisitions). The professor told me I should "control for year and industry (Fama French 12 - ffinds) fixed effects and adjust heteroskedasticity-robust standard errors for bidder clustering".

Here is what I have tried to do:

1. `fracreg logit Y X1 X2 i.Year i.ffinds, vce(cluster ID)`
2. `glm Y X1 X2 i.Year i.ffinds, family(binomial) link(logit) robust nolog` , but I cannot cluster for ID
3. I have tried to use `xtlogit`, but I am not able to apply it to multiple fixed effects

Which one is the correct approach? Also, using `i.Year` and `i.ffinds` I have too many dummies in the output. Is there a way to suppress them (like the option `absorb` used with `reg`)?

Comment: I would have thought from the details you give that beta regression was the way forward. I have no idea how to do that in Stata and anyway asking for code is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example is exactly how I would have done it.

- Modeling proportions is what fracreg is for (although it's not the only way, with beta regression being the obvious alternative).
- You're controlling for year and industry.
- You're adjusting the standard errors in the way he requested.

The second example, even if you could get it to work right (offhand, I'm surprised you can't use a cluster VCE here), would give you the same answer as the first.  That's how fractional logistic regression used to be done in Stata, using glm with certain options.

I strongly suspect the third example wouldn't work even if you could get the specification right; I don't know for sure, but I've never seen any research on estimating fixed-effect fractional logit models, let alone research that suggests you can just call the likelihood a quasi-likelihood and charge ahead.